# Apache unable to write on 2777 folder

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions, centos7

I am using smarty template system on my website.

When it tries to cache some data, a fatal error occurs:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir '/var/www/html/cache/frontend'. Be sure $compile_dir is writable by the web server user. in /var/www/html/include/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1092
```

I just get my vps today (Centos 7) and made basic LAMP setup.

I have uploaded all the content inside /var/www/html using sftp (root user).
Then I have (still using filezilla) set /var/www/html/cache and all it's files/subdirectories to 777.

Whatever I try I can't get apache it to write on the cache folder or subfolder.

And the strange thing is that when doing

```
[root@localhost ~]# chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/cache
```

the cache folder is still set to 2777.

I have also tried to make "apache" as the owner of /var/www/html/cache and all it's files/subdirectories but I still can't write on it.

I am completly lost and very newbie when it comes to server setup.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check the permissions on all directories above - `/var`, `/var/www` and `/var/www/html`.

Comment: If you had provided the relevant information from your logs, in particular the audit log and error_log we may have been able to help you solve this correctly. Disabling SELinux may be expedient but it is almost never the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating /var/www/html/cache/frontend?

```
mkdir /var/www/html/cache/frontend
chown apache /var/www/html/cache/frontend
chmod 0750 /var/www/html/cache/frontend
```

Answer (score -2):

I have fixed the problem by disabling SELinux.

I have used the command: `setenforce 0`

Then I was able to chmod to 0777 the cache folder and all it's subdir from filezilla, logging using SFTP.

Hope it can help somebody

Comment: Instead of disabling SElinux - why don't you spend  bit of time learning it and fix the problem correctly ? Disabling SElinux is (almost never) the correct answer.